# Blend for Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

According to [this announcement](http://blendinsider.com/technical/available-now-blend-for-visual-studio-2012-2012-08-15/), the right version of Blend to use for Silverlight 5 development is Blend Preview for Silverlight 5, but that expired a while ago. I was using the [Blend + SketchFlow Preview for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702) since, but that expired today.

It seems that not only is there still no version of Expression Blend released that supports Silverlight 5, but the two previews that do have both expired.

Does anybody know about a workaround or anything I have overlooked?

Comment: You can with the Delorean :) : go back to past (before the expiration day)... Start Blend and when blend is started, Back to the present.

Comment: That 'announcement' now automatically redirects to http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Blend for Visual Studio now fully supports Silverlight 5 when Update 2 is installed.

I got this information [from the blend support forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/9bd3cce4-0f71-4b65-a81e-766695c86e78/blend-preview-for-silverlight-5-expired).

Comment: Could you post the link for the blend support forum article and if possible a download link for Update 2 or instructions of how to get it? (I think there might even be update 3 now, I also read that the Blend for Silverlight 5 Preview is much more stable than these updates)

Comment: @CodeBlend I added the link. I use update 3 and I can't say that Blend is less (or more) stable than the preview used to be. All in all I'm happy that there's only one Blend now instead of three.